# How can I use javascript to detect an inline link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a web page `index.html`. Suppose the client goes to `index.html#section2`. This should take the client to the section of the page with a block-level element having a name attribute of `section2`.

How do I detect this inline link in javascript? Specifically, if the user goes to `index.html#section2`,  I want to run a certain function in javascript.

I am open to using jQuery as well. Thank you!

Comment: Having an `id` attribute of `section2`; `name` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery with this jQuery plugin
http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Then you can do:

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function( event ) {
    if(window.location.hash === "#section2"){
        // What you want to do
    }
})
```

Or if you dont want to use jQuery just use onclick events.

```
<a href="#section2" onclick="changed()"></a>
```

JS:

```
function changed(){
        setTimeout(function(){
                if(window.location.hash === "#section2"){
                    // What you want to do
                }
        })
}
window.onload = changed; // In case user starts on #section2
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the jQuery solution. Apparently, it works without the plugin. Hmm.

Comment: @ChiZeng The plugin is for browsers that don't support the `window.hashchange` event.

Comment: The downside of not using the `hashchange` event is the state of that application can be thrown off if the `hash` changes by some other means than clicking on an anchor...

Answer (score 1):

Do a `switch` on the `window.location.hash` property.

```
switch(window.location.hash) {    
   case '#section1':
      foo();
   case '#section2':
      bar();
}
```

**Note** - The `hash` property is supported in all major browsers.

**Edit** - 
*@IvanCastellanos* is right about the new `hashchange` event and the lack of support in down-level browsers. If the OP needs to handle this situation then the overhead of the plugin may be necessary - as pointed out in his answer...

Comment: This solution only works if the user starts on index.html#section2 but not if the user clicks the link inside the page itself.